# Ordering extended discriminated unions

Tags: f#, comparison, discriminated-union

Assuming one has a class of discriminated unions such as:

```
type IAnimal =
    end interface

type Mammal =
    | Cat
    | Dog
    | Cow
    | Sheep
    interface IAnimal   

type Reptile =
    | Tortoise
    | Lizard
    | Snake
    | Crocodile        
    interface IAnimal
```

And one wants a set of `IAnimal` such as:

```
let animals = set [Cat :> IAnimal; Lizard :> IAnimal]
```

This will fail with `The type IAnimal does not support the 'comparison' constraint`.

It is possible to remedy this by inheriting the `IComparable` interface in `IAnimal`, but this will force me to explictly implement `CompareTo(obj)` in both `Mammal` and `Reptile` despite them supporting comparison internally. What I would like to do is just make sure that they are comparable to eachother without having to implement alot of "redundant" comparison logic to do so.

Answer (score 4):

A more idiomatic F# way would be to define another discriminated union which is either mammal or reptile:

```
type Mammal =
    | Cat
    | Dog
    | Cow
    | Sheep

type Reptile =
    | Tortoise
    | Lizard
    | Snake
    | Crocodile        

type Animal =
    | Reptile of Reptile
    | Mammal of Mammal
```

Then you can create a set of animals, because F# implements comparison on the `Animal` union for you:

```
let animals = set [Mammal Cat; Reptile Lizard]
```

Using an interface might make sense in certain scenarios, but it very much depends on the use case. So for an example with animals, this is probably the most reasonable approach.

Comment: Yes in this example you are right, it makes more sense. But my actual use case is a bit different, I have a "base" DU and I need to be able to extend it from another assembly that has unit tests.

Comment: I think there should usually be a way of avoiding that kind of situation, but it is hard to say without knowing more about your specific case. Could you perhaps share some more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a similar DU with only "unit cases" but they are domain-specific, I want to test the logic of this particular subsystem but I want the tests to be more general so I want to make a DU with "general cases" instead of domain-specific ones.

Comment: And what is the logic that you are testing? If it works on `Mammal` and `Reptile`, then there should be a way to make it work over any DU...